# Switching postdoc position (station) in China

Tags: postdocs, china

I had applied for postdoc in a university in China, all documentation went through and my was successful in that funds were approved @ 120 K RMB (lowest) + 30K and housing etc. I received the work permit from the school, and then the pandemic came, I wasn't able to even apply for the Z visa. This happened around December 2019 - January 2020. The permit expired and as of today I haven't heard anything from the school. In the meantime, I have found another better postdoc offer from Beijing, the documentation hasn't started yet but I am concerned that my information might already be in the system linked to the previous school. How do I get rid of the previous school or do I need to worry at all? Because I never started the first position in the first place, and I prefer to chose this new offer instead of the previous. Anyone who has experience with Chinese postdoc system might be able to help and guide. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you ask the people running the system and also inform the one you don't want - just out of manners if nothing else.

Comment: quite right.. I was thinking about it too..

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through the process of registering on chinapostdoctor.org? If so, then you are probably right that you are in a system somewhere. However, this should not affect anything because you never actually started your original position.

Nevertheless, I would proactively explain your situation to your current prospective supervisor so they (or their students) will be prepared to help you in case of any snags.

No matter what, it will not be an issue that derails your appointment. If there is an issue, it will be a clerical one that can be sorted out by the school with a phone call or two.

Comment: No I didnt register myself at chinapostdoctor.org, however, the (first) school might have done so for me? I didn't do it by myself though.

Comment: unlikely they would have done this without you. but either way it shouldn't matter.